# Getting user credentials using Google+ API

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to include **Google sign in** in my android application using **Google+ Api.** I am able to take account details from the user but once signed in I am getting **null** when **requesting for username** using call:

> Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient).getDisplayName()

And Logcat shows:

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for
>   https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

Although I am able to get email of the user using:

> Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(GoogleClient.mGoogleApiClient)

Please help me to discover my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried same code and its working fine!
So, just ensure two things:

1)Register your digitally signed .apk file's public certificate in the Google APIs Console.Link below:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_api

2)Make sure you have added the google+ api access and have client key created with SHA1.
Rest is fine.

Comment: I want to know can I skip the part of adding configuration file instead can mention API key in Android manifest?

Comment: @sv_jan5 which config file? Just follow the document steps only- Add project on google console,enable g+ api ,generate key using SHA, Add gms library to your android project and use the sample code to configure the G+. that's it

Comment: acutally I am using android studio for building my app so i am following this guide https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating for integrating the google sign-in. In this it is mentioned to include a configuration file

Comment: @sv_jan5 I too use Android Studio only and I have implemented using above link. It is working perfect and easy to follow steps.Follow above links and wherever you are stuck I can help you.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to know the link which you have mentioned in that are we giving some authentication information to the application in form of API key etc.?

Comment: @sv_jan5 I did it a while ago, but still I remember that we only need to enter package name and SHA key only google console.Nothing on app site and it works like charm.Please accept it as answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

I think basic steps of google+ login integration in app is known by you.Here are the rest of the steps

step 1--
in oncreate

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
         .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
         .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
         .addApi(Plus.API)
         .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
         .build();
```

step 2--
in login button click listener call this----

```
private void LoginGoogle(){
        int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (errorCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
          GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
        }
        else{
            //perform login
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mSignInClicked = true;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            }
        }
    }
```

step 3----
in onActivityresult

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) { 
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                  mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
              mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();
            }
          }

step 4-----

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!mIntentInProgress){
            if ( mSignInClicked && result.hasResolution()) {
                 // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
                  // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                  try {
                    result.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIntentInProgress = true;
                  } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                    // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                    mIntentInProgress = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                  }

              }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mSignInClicked = false;
        getProfileInformation();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
              mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }

    }
```

step 5-----

```
private void getProfileInformation(){
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String id=currentPerson.getId();
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                String profilePic=personPhoto.substring(0,
                        personPhoto.length() - 2)
                        + ProfilePicSize;

                Log.e("GOOGLE", id);
                Log.e("GOOGLE", personName);
                Log.e("GOOGLE", profilePic);
                Log.e("GOOGLE",email);


              }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```